# Categorical formulations of basic results and ideas from functional analysis?

Tags: functional-analysis, category-theory, big-list, big-picture

I'm taking a first (undergrad) course on functional analysis. Though the material is nice, the approach seems very ad hoc and in a sense, near-sighted (?).

I was wondering whether the/a big picture of (parts of) the elementary landscape of functional analysis admits some nice categorical descriptions.

What are some basic facts, theorems, and constructions in elementary functional analysis admit enlightening categorical formulations?

Comment: nLab is an encyclopedia of mathematics with a bias towards category theory. See their article of [functional analysis](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/functional+analysis).

Comment: I would be very interested on the same topic, any more info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Lectures and Exercises on Functional Analysis by A. Y. Helemskii](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821840983) might be exactly what you're looking for. Quoting from the introduction:

> Perhaps the main idea is that our book is written from the categorical
>   point of view. Everywhere we stress and comment on the categorical nature of the fundamental constructions and results (like the
>   constructions of adjoint operators and completion, the Riesz-Fischer
>   and the Schmidt theorems, and closer to the end of the book, the
>   great Hilbert spectral theorem). This, as we believe, provides a new
>   level of understanding of the topics discussed. We are sure that
>   students (and even professors!) are ready for the perception of the
>   very basic categorical notions (and only those are used) and, what is
>   more important, for the unifying mathematical language of category
>   theory. Functional analysis, with its synthetic algebraic and topological content, works very well for first acquaintance with
>   categories, the same way as "Analysis III" did for the exposition of
>   the foundations of set theory 50 years ago. (Of course, the exposition
>   must be accompanied by a sufficient supply of examples and exercises;
>   but we shall discuss this later.)

Comment: Yes, that book is wonderful! However, the topics it covers are only the most classical ones, so no Fréchet, nuclear space etc.